# Background image not displaying on any IE version

Tags: html, css, background-image

Here is my code which is not working on any version of IE -

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))), url("../img/archi.png") repeat 0 0;
background: -moz-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))), url("../img/archi.png") repeat 0 0;
background: gradient(to linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))), url("../img/archi.png") repeat 0 0;
background: -o-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))), url("../img/archi.png") repeat 0 0;
```

Comment: updated my answer after you accepted as i had forgotten to add your image to the end of the gradient. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 gradient backgrounds only work in IE10 and 11 by targeting the `-ms-` prefix. http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient However, you can use the non-standard gradient `filter` for below that.

I would recommend using something like the following to generate gradients http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

It will give you options to import your current CSS to generate an output that's relatively crossbrowser compliant.

However, you have some syntax errors in the way your gradients are written, and should order them so that the most standards compliant is last in the list (MS's filter not withstanding). Here is what they should be:

```
background: url("../img/archi.png") repeat 0 0; /* fallback for gradient */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url("../img/archi.png") repeat 0 0; /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))), url("../img/archi.png") repeat 0 0; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url("../img/archi.png") repeat 0 0; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url("../img/archi.png") repeat 0 0; /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url("../img/archi.png") repeat 0 0; /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url("../img/archi.png") repeat 0 0; /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1affffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```